# Do CHF3 and acetone form a hydrogen bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request, intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond

I haven't been able to find a reference confirming that fluoroform forms hydrogen bonds with acetone. Do they?

Comment: See https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/chem_facpub/198/ and https://socratic.org/questions/592bd4b8b72cff0244178cc7

Comment: Apparently, it depends on your definition of a [weak hydrogen bond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%E2%80%93H%C2%B7%C2%B7%C2%B7O_interaction). @Avon97

Comment: See also [Hydrogen-bond dynamics of C-H...O interactions: the chloroform...acetone case](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20648487/)

Comment: Acetone's $\ce{H}$ and  fluoroform's $\ce{F}$ and Acetone's $\ce{O}$ and fluoroform's $\ce{H}$ can H-bond simultaneously (You can visualize this by aligning the molecules)

Comment: @KarstenTheis Can $\ce{F}$ and $\ce{H}$, H bond in here other and $\ce{O}$ and $\ce{H}$ ? Its confusing in here with both H bonds the intermolecular force is strong.

Comment: [This might help in your problem](http://www.cryst.bbk.ac.uk/PPS2/projects/day/TDayDiss/HBonds.html)